# Update order after success or failed payment in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway, woocommerce-rest-api

I integrated a custom payment gateway for woocommerce, I have successfully done it and able to output success / failure and redirects correctly along with emptying the cart.. 
Redirects correctly
Emptys cart
Does not update order_status or add_order_note

```
function check_pg_response($order_id)
{
global $woocommerce;
    $msg['class']   = 'error';
    $msg['message'] = $this->settings['error_msg']." - Error: No Response From Payment Gateway.";

if (isset($_REQUEST['msg'])){
$response = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$response_data = array();
$resp = explode("|", $response);
$dataSize=sizeof($resp);
    for($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i++) 
                {
                    $information=explode('=',$resp[$i]);
                    if($i==0)   $txn_status=$information[1]; //001   
                    if($i==1)   $txn_msg=$information[1]; // success or failure
                    if($i==2)   $txn_err_msg=$information[1]; // canceled by user   
                    if($i==3)   $txn_ref=$information[1];
                    if($i==4)   $bank_cd=$information[1];
                    if($i==5)   $txn_id=$information[1];    
                    if($i==6)   $txn_amt=$information[1];
                    if($i==7)   $txn_time=$information[1];    
                }
        }
if($order -> status !=='completed'){
$order_id = (int) $order_id;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ($txn_msg=='success'){
        $transauthorised = true;
        $msg['message']  = $this->settings['success_msg'];
        $msg['class']    = 'success';
if ($order->status != 'processing') {
        $order->payment_complete();
        $order->update_status('completed', __('Payment Successful.', 'wptut'));
        $order->add_order_note('PG ID: '.$clnt_txn_ref.'<br/> Transaction ID: '.$tpsl_txn_id.'<br/>Bank CD: '.$tpsl_bank_cd);
        $woocommerce -> cart -> empty_cart();}

        } 
        else if($txn_msg=='failure'){
        $msg['class']   = 'error';
        $msg['message'] = $this->settings['declined_msg']." - Error: Payment Gateway Declined order.";
        $order->update_status('failed', __('Payment has been cancelled.', 'wptut'));
        $order->add_order_note('PG payment failed<br/>Techprocess ID: '.$txn_ref.'<br/>Payment Gateway Message: '.$txn_err_msg);
        $woocommerce -> cart -> empty_cart();
    }else{
        $msg['class']   = 'error';
        $msg['message'] = $this->settings['error_msg']." - Error: Unknown Error";
    }

    if ($transauthorised == false) {
        $order->update_status('failed');
        $order->add_order_note($msg['message']);
    }
    }


if (function_exists('wc_add_notice')) {
    wc_add_notice($msg['message'], $msg['class']);

} else {
    if ($msg['class'] == 'success') {
        $woocommerce->add_message($msg['message']);
    } else {
        $woocommerce->add_error($msg['message']);

    }
    $woocommerce->set_messages();
}
$redirect_url = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount'));
wp_redirect($redirect_url);
exit;
```

}
}

Comment: did you extend woocommerce `WC_Payment_Gateway` to your payment gateway class?

Comment: Yeh.. add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_pg_init', 0);
function woocommerce_pg_init(){
  if(!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) return;  class WC_pg extends WC_Payment_Gateway{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Woocommerce, to make custom Payment gateway you will have to override `WC_Payment_Gateway's` class functions.

[do_order_complete_tasks](https://github.com/wp-plugins/woocommerce-paypal-pro-payment-gateway/blob/master/woo-paypal-pro-gateway-class.php#L222-L236) function handle the action before order complete.

```
 protected function do_order_complete_tasks()
     {

          global $woocommerce;

          // return if order status id already completed.
          if ($this->order->status == 'completed')
               return;

          $this->order->payment_complete();
          $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

          // add order note 
          $this->order->add_order_note(sprintf("Order completed with Transaction Id of '%s'", $this->transactionId));

     }
```

[process_payment](https://github.com/wp-plugins/woocommerce-paypal-pro-payment-gateway/blob/master/woo-paypal-pro-gateway-class.php#L192-L208) function To handle the order process of payment

```
    function process_payment($order_id)
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        $this->order        = new WC_Order($order_id);

            // calling do_order_complete_tasks() function. 
            $this->do_order_complete_tasks();

            return array(
                'result' => 'success',
                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url($this->order)
            );

    }
```

add this two functions  inside your custom WC payment gateway class and modify according to your need.

Hope this help!

Comment: Getting error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 1

Comment: @PSebastian copy `process_payment` function from my answer  and replace in your code, i have just edited.  it is now updating and adding order note both is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, But I still cannot add_order_note ? and also checking out again.. it does not process it as "new order" but records it as payment done.. without going to PG..

Comment: @PSebastian Oops, i added `get_return_url()` instead of checkout payment url. So, In process function replace redirect value to `'redirect' => $this->order->get_checkout_payment_url(true)` so that it can redirect to receipt page to make payment.

Comment: I tried with the changed value too "This order’s status is “Processing”—it cannot be paid for. Please contact us if you need assistance."

Comment: can you please comment this line `$this->do_order_complete_tasks();` @PSebastian

Comment: Same as - Redirects correctly Emptys cart Does not update order_status or add_order_note

Comment: it is because you didn't call `$this->do_order_complete_tasks()` in your api callback function 'check_techprocess_response' call `$this->do_order_complete_tasks()` function below your `$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();` in success and failure block. @PSebastian

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function payment_complete() on a non-object [link] https://wp-witness.rhcloud.com/ credentials user/actnow bank test/test

Comment: remove  `$this->order->payment_complete();` from line 264 as you already has called inside you api callback function. @PSebastian

Comment: line 261 Notice: Undefined property: WC_tp::$order , line 264 Call to a member function add_order_note() on a non-object

Comment: Thanks, but still unable to complete order. Fatal error: Call to a member function add_order_note() 267